# Select first row from join with grouped data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have two separate queries which I am trying to efficently join.

```
Query 1:
Select Id From Accounts Where Status='OPEN' and Product = 'Product A'


Query 2: 
Select AccountId From Transactions Group By AccountId Having Count(*) > 20;
```

Table transactions hold millions of rows.

What I want to achieve is to return the first account in an open status with product A having more than 20 transactions.

So far i got this, but it is not very efficent due to full table scan of transaction table:

```
Select A.Id From Accounts A 
Left Outer Join (Select AccountId From Transactions Group By AccountId Having Count(*) > 20 ) T on A.Id=T.AccountId
Where A.Status='OPEN' and A.Product = 'Product A'
And rownum = 1
```

How do I optimize this query?

Comment: Do transactions have an index? If not, creating one will improve perfomance

Comment: transactions.accountid is indexed. Table is also partitioned with a unique key for each month.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be better, filtering the specific accounts and grouping ??

```
Select AccountId From Transactions where AccountId in (Select id From Accounts Where Status='OPEN' and Product = 'Product A') Group By AccountId Having Count(*) > 20;
```

Comment: cost/cardinality is still very high.

Comment: @MrM - but that isn't the question, is it? The question is, "is this Answer better than your original query." The answer is not obvious, it can go either way depending on your actual data. Is the cardinality with Srikanth's answer only 70% of the cardinality with your original attempt? Great, it saves you 30% of time and resources! You may not be able to query a table with millions of rows, join, group and count in 0.001 seconds, that would be an unreasonable expectation.